# How to use Mustache.js if the object is in a array?

Tags: javascript, mustache

i use Mustache.js succusefully display the html ,here's the code

```
        var mygame = {
        player:'viking',
        games:[{name:'d1',type:'avg'},{name:'cod7',type:'fps'},{name:'war3',type:'rts'}]
        };
    var template = '{{player}}  is a good guy<br/> <ul>{{#games}}<li>name:{{name}} and type:{{type}} </li>{{/games}}</ul>';
    var html = Mustache.to_html(template, mygame);
    var con = document.getElementById('container');
    con.innerHTML = html;
```

but how do i use it when the object is a array ,like

```
var mygames = [{name:'d1',type:'avg'},{name:'cod7',type:'fps'},{name:'war3',type:'rts'}];
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
var mygames = [{name:'d1',type:'avg'},{name:'cod7',type:'fps'},{name:'war3',type:'rts'}];

var mygame = {
    player: 'viking',
    games: mygames
}
var template = '{{player}} is a good guy<br /> <ul>{{#games}}<li>name:{{name}} and type:{{type}} </li>{{/games}}</ul>';
var html = Mustache.to_html(template, mygame);
var con = document.getElementById('container');
con.innerHTML = html;
```

Comment: Mustache.js can't use array as a parameter？ I don't want  wrap my array in a object

Answer (score 36):

You can do it like this:

```
var model = [{name:'d1',type:'avg'},{name:'cod7',type:'fps'},{name:'war3',type:'rts'}];
var template = '<ul> {{#.}} <li>name:{{name}} and type:{{type}} </li> {{/.}} </ul>';
var html = Mustache.to_html(template, model);
```

Comment: The other answers just present ways to avoid the circumstance.  Since this shows that mustache syntax actually does allow you to use an array as the data object without wrapping it in fluff, this should really be the accepted answer.

Comment: Great solution. Have searched for half of all internet to find this elegant answer.

Answer (score 2):

you need to do something like this:

```
var mygames = {games: [{name:'d1',type:'avg'},{name:'cod7',type:'fps'},{name:'war3',type:'rts'}]};

var template= "{{#games}} Player name: {{name}} Type: {{type}}{{/games}}";

var html = Mustache.to_html(template, mygames);
var con = document.getElementById('container');
con.innerHTML = html;
```

or simply loop over mygames object and append the html

```
var html="";
var template= "Player name: {{name}} Type: {{type}};"
for (var i=0;i<mygames.length;i++)
{
   html+=Mustache.to_html(template, mygames[i]);
}
var con = document.getElementById('container');
con.innerHTML = html;
```

Hope this helps